# Receive Run-time Error 58 File Already Exists When It Doesn't

Tags: excel, vba

I keep on receiving

> "Run-time Error 58 File Already Exists"

when trying to run the below code. I've double and triple checked and the file definitely doesn't exist.

I run a different Macro first that gets me the location of the folder I want to create this new folder in. The location is displayed in `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`. `Master File` is the name of the new folder I want to create.

```
Sub CreateFolder

Dim Bname As String
Bname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Text & "\Master File"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateFolder "Bname"

End Sub
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Sub CreateFolder

Dim Bname As String
Bname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Text & "\Master File"
MkDir "Bname"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify your program. You are probably using a 32 bit program AND writing somewhere you aren't allowed. Hence it will be virtualised. Look under `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create folder 'Bname', not '..\Master File'. Do not use quotation marks around the variable.

```
fso.CreateFolder Bname
```